# Neo4jclient ALL predicate

Tags: neo4j, cypher, predicate, neo4jclient

I have Following query

```
MATCH (p:Product)-[r9:SCP_HAS_SCMVSV]-(scmvsv:ProductSCMVSValue) WHERE 
scmvsv.Id IN ["63dc2250-77c3-4cdb-888b-b2420eaee1f1",
"4571cef2-45bb-41cc-8954-b8e8b8ee6d7d"]
return p
```

it returns all products that are related to any values to in parameter,
I need return all products that are related to ALL values in parameter

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, you need to return all the products that have the relationship [:SCP_HAS_SCMVSV] with ProductSCMVSValue?

Comment: Could you write some sort of pseudo code as to what you want to happen?

Comment: I have Products with  multi ProductSCMVSValue like color, size, material , ... . I have search panel that create query dynamic by options, when i run above query it return for example products that are blue or Medium but i need to return products that are blue and Medium together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a product with relationships to multiple ProductSCMVSValue labeled nodes - do this:

```
MATCH (p:Product)-[r9:SCP_HAS_SCMVSV]-(:ProductSCMVSValue {id: "63dc2250-77c3-4cdb-888b-b2420eaee1f1"})
MATCH (p)-[r9:SCP_HAS_SCMVSV]-(:ProductSCMVSValue {id: "4571cef2-45bb-41cc-8954-b8e8b8ee6d7d"})
return p
```

add more MATCH() lines to add more values to the match criteria.